# Where Do I Download TraceMonkey?

Tags: javascript, v8, spidermonkey, tracemonkey

I can get the Spidermonkey javascript engine from here:

http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/

And, I know that Tracemonkey is the newer version released after SpiderMonkey but I cannot find the download link for it in Mozilla?  Is it released for public use?  Should I stick back to SpiderMonkey or switch to Google's V8 altogether - if TraceMonkey is not available for public download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TraceMonkey is a patch set that has been applied to SpiderMonkey when you get the latest version of SpiderMonkey you get TraceMonkey. See http://ejohn.org/blog/tracemonkey/

Answer (score 0):

TraceMonkey is part of FireFox version 3.1 and above.  you still have to know how to enable it to take advantage. Here's how it works:

1. Open about:config in your browser.
2. Paste javascript.options.jit.content into the filter.
3. Double-click the remaining preference to set the boolean to true.

**EDIT**

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

http://hg.mozilla.org/tracemonkey

Comment: Thanks, I mean getting the source code of the Javascript engine and embedding javascript into my own C++/C application.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want it for embedding, but for those who just want to use Tracemonkey/Spidermonkey, a nice way is to install Firefox and the [Prism add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6665/) which allows you to turn a web page (or URL) into an application. Not quite the same as Microsoft's .HTA files, but if you can write your app inside a web page this will work.